# How can I detach a database that is in use?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Even though nothing is using it I am unable to detach a database because it is use.

```
Cannot detach the database 'DEMO' because it is currently in use.
```

I have tried rebooting and get the same message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
--Kick all users off of the database NOW
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

--Kick all but after 60 seconds
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK AFTER 60 SECONDS

--restore connection to users
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried checking the "Drop Connections" box when you detach it?

Comment: I was hoping more for a query related solution. Server Management Studio Express very often causes my machine to blue screen. So I'm using a tool that just sends queries to the server.

Comment: A blue screen is usually related to hardware or OS-level problems, not to some very specific application such as a database management tool. I can't imagine why this particular program makes your machine crash, but this is definitely a symptom of some underlying serious problem.

Comment: It is some combination of Visual Studio and Server Management Studio Express, because I have seen the behavior on 3 different workstations. It might be from running multiple versions of Visual Studio at once, I know this causes bizarre behavior in IE7 when using tabs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect from server.
2. Restart the SQL Server service to close all connections.
3. Log in with Windows Authentication.
4. Easily detach the database.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check "Drop Connections" from "Detach Database" window, otherwise it's very simple and just choose detach from the menu, see the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This command should drop all connections, then allow you to detach.

ALTER DATABASE  SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK_IMMEDIATE